# The duplicate object resulting from the mirror modifier does not follow the others when changing position

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm trying to follow this tutorial;
https://youtu.be/au5bwPB5pi8&t=6m23s

[image]

After pressing R-X-then typing 60 degrees, the duplicate result of the mirror modifier I used does not follow. Making the result like this :
[image]

The file : https://blend-exchange.com/b/3Xzwb6bq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the object called *Plane.001* as *Mirror Object*, if you move away or rotate *Plane.004* (object with the *Mirror* modifier), it will change its relative location or angle to the mirror object, the mirrored part will move or rotate as well.

To fix that you either need to apply the modifier or choose another mirror object, like for *Plane.002* to which the object is parented.